# Как сделать форму заставки во время загрузки придожения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, async-await, qsplashscreen

Запуск программы на *PyQt5* занимает какое-то время и в это время ничего не происходит, то есть можно подумать, что программа попросту не запускается.

Поэтому я решила на время загрузки добавить отдельную форму, как это сделано во многих приложениях, которая будет висеть, пока не загрузится основная форма.

Но после многих попыток у меня не вышло правильно реализовать свою задумку, если поместить инициализацию основной формы в `def __init__(self)`, то  ни одна форма не запускается, пока обе не прогрузятся полностью, это логично:

```
class LoadingForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...

        self.main_window = Window()
        self.main_window.show()
        self.hide()
```

Далее я попробовала сделать запуск основной формы после нажатия на форму загрузки:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.main_window = Window()
        self.main_window.show()
        self.hide()
```

Этот вариант сработал, но вся обработка происходит уже после нажатия кнопки и поэтому форма загрузки просто зависает, а также это не совсем подходящий вариант, так как нужно нажать кнопкой на форму. Я использую [qasync](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync) и, чтобы избавиться от зависания, попробовала такой вариант:

```
@asyncSlot
async def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.main_window = Window()
        self.main_window.show()
        self.hide()
```

Такой код выдаёт ошибку:

> TypeError: outer_decorator() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Как правильно реализовать форму загрузки?

Через `qasync` или другим способом. Загрузка формы не очень долгая **`1-3`** секунды, можно было бы и сделать таймер и после истечения времени, показывать уже загруженную форму. 
Насколько такой вариант правильный?

---

**Вот весь код:**

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from qasync import asyncSlot, asyncClose, QApplication
import asyncio
import functools
import qasync
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class LoadingForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Loading Form')
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 620, 300)
        self.press = False
        self.last_pos = QPoint(0, 0)

        box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        movie = PyQt5.QtGui.QMovie('loading.gif')
        lbl = QLabel(self)
        lbl.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        box.addWidget(lbl)

        self.setWindowOpacity(0.6)
        self.centerOnScreen()


    def centerOnScreen(self):
        resolution = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.move((resolution.width() / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2),
                  (resolution.height() / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
            if self.press:
                self.move(event.globalPos() - self.last_pos)

    @asyncSlot # Тут ошибка
    async def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = True
            self.main_window = Window()
            self.main_window.show()
            self.hide()

        self.last_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = False


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # super(Window, self).__init__()
        # uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)

        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Form')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 620, 300)


async def main():
    def close_future(future, loop):
        loop.call_later(10, future.cancel)
        future.cancel("Close Application")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.Future()

    app = QApplication.instance()
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    if hasattr(app, 'aboutToQuit'):
        getattr(app, 'aboutToQuit').connect(functools.partial(close_future, future, loop))

    window = LoadingForm()
    window.show()

    await future

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        qasync.run(main())
    except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: `QSplashScreen` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html

Comment: По-моему, дичь какая-то это Qt с корунтинами/задачами :) Там ведь есть решения через потоки. Для скачивания можно использовать специальный класс QNetworkAccessManager. У меня есть парочка примеров, посмотрите: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/93fecde57300f9c6e4fa86cb4433f126ef0507f3/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/URLView__download_and_show_image_on_label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `QSplashScreen` позволяет нам создавать заставки.
Заставка обеспечивает обратную связь с пользователем о том, что приложение загружается.

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSplashScreen, QWidget, \
    QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout


class GifSplashScreen(QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GifSplashScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.movie = QMovie('Data/splash.gif')
        self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.onFrameChanged)
        self.movie.start()

    def onFrameChanged(self, _):
        self.setPixmap(self.movie.currentPixmap())

    def finish(self, widget):
        self.movie.stop()
        super(GifSplashScreen, self).finish(widget)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):                         
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Form')
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.label = QLabel('<h1>Hello World.</h1>')
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash = GifSplashScreen()
    splash.show()

    def createWindow():
        app.w = MainWindow()                             
        # Имитация начального отображения через 3 секунды
        splash.showMessage(
            'Ожидание отображения интерфейса', 
            Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom, Qt.white
        )
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: (
            splash.showMessage(
                'Загрузка завершена', 
                Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom, Qt.white
            ), 
            app.w.show(),
            splash.finish(app.w))
        )

    # Симуляция занимает 6 секунд. Вы не можете использовать sleep.
    # Можете использовать дочерние потоки для загрузки трудоемких данных.
    # Интерфейс настройки цикла в основном потоке может взаимодействовать с 
    # QApplication.instance().processEvents()
    splash.showMessage(
        'Ожидание создания интерфейса', 
        Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom, Qt.white
    )
    QTimer.singleShot(3000, createWindow)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему бы просто `super()` не использовать, типа `super().finish(widget)`? :)